# dirPagination - AngularJS issue

Tags: angularjs, pagination, single-page-application, paging

SCANERIO: i am working on a angularjs application. It has a page that has a pagination using dir pagination. That page works fine, That page also calls a dialog pop up page which also has pagination.

THE PROBLEM: saying the main page returns 30 records then a record is selected which then calls a dialog pop which it calls a service and returns just 2 records. if i cancel from the dialog the main page pagination returns to just 2 records and not the 30 records it had before. some how the paginations of the dialog is over writing the main page.

HOW do i reset pagination on the page when cancelling out of the dialog pop page?

Comment: Try to give different id to your `dirPagination` and can you add this in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

> **pagination-id** (optional) Used to group together the dir-pagination-controls with a corresponding dir-paginate when you need more than one pagination instance per page. See the section below on setting up multiple instances.

You can define pagination-id on each paging directive you use this will not effect others. Looks [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) for syntax.